# I want to access the Case number or case id on Custom LiveAgent chat window.

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, liveagent, service-cloud-console

I am using the salesfroce custome liveagent chat window. When i end the case the the getfeedback (App on app-exchange ) opens in same chat window. Here i want to pass the case number and the ContactId because the get feedback will save the record under the particular case ID.

I am using the following code to initiate the chat and at the same time i am creating the case as well.

liveagent.addCustomDetail('Param1Test_Name','GenePoint' );
    liveagent.addCustomDetail('ChatStatus', 'New' );
    liveagent.addCustomDetail('pName','{!$CurrentPage.parameters.pName}' );

```
liveagent.addCustomDetail('sessionName','{!$CurrentPage.parameters.session_id}' );


liveagent.findOrCreate("Case").map("Status", "ChatStatus", false, false, true);
liveagent.findOrCreate("Case").map("Product_Name__c", "pName", false, false, true);
liveagent.findOrCreate("Case").showOnCreate();
liveagent.findOrCreate("Case").map("Session_Id__c", "sessionName", false, false, true);

liveagent.findOrCreate("Case").saveToTranscript("CaseId");

liveagent.init('https://d.la4-c1cs-was.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572550000004CAf', '00D550000005PUI');
```

Can you please let me know or help me that when i click on the End Chat (**Standard button of live agent**) the Page should be redirect to the Get Feedback URL with the related **Case ID** and **Contact ID**

https://xyzabc.com?CaseId=ab667fddj &ContactId=67gjjhjh778